# Asp.net Core Problem While Authorizing Through FusionAuth

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, fusionauth

I followed the [this](https://fusionauth.io/blog/2020/05/06/securing-asp-netcore-razor-pages-app-with-oauth/) article to configure my asp.net core application's authentication using FusionAuth. I created an application on their Sandbox account (cloud hosted application) instead of hosting it at my local pc.
Everything looks fine, it redirects me to fusionAuth login page when I click on a secure page but after login it redirects me to `http://localhost:5000/signin-oidc` and show the following page

[image]

I can't find enough help on this topic, can anyone please guide me further?

Comment: Does this error appear when you run fusionauth locally?

Comment: No, I am using sandbox account `https://sandbox.fusionauth.io` @mooreds

Comment: You may change to development mode to see the detail error messages.

Comment: @lali you could install FusionAuth locally to try to see whether the issue is because of the configuration of the sandbox, an HTTP/HTTPS issue or something else.